# What are the reasons for stackexchange sites not providing the option to highlight text with colors?

Tags: discussion, design

As the title says:

Why is there no option to highlight portions of text using color? We **do** have to option of using different *fonts*.

Edit: I actually wrote

```
<blue>color</blue>
```

but pseudo-html tags seem to get filtered (I think my next question is going to be why ;) )

Comment: If you feel that the feature of being able to highlight content would be valuable, propose that feature, and explain why you think it merits implementation.  Discussing why someone choose not to implement a feature isn't a particularly sensible question.

Comment: Higlight every word of ur question with different color and then try to read it ;) and on your last sentence: yes, unicorning words or letters is forbidden,  what do you expect?

Comment: Whenever someone asks why SE doesn't implement something, I think about this blog post by Eric Lippert - [How many Microsoft employees does it take to change a lightbulb?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb.aspx). Features have costs - and the benefits should outweigh the costs.

Comment: As for why pseudo-html tags being stripped? Because they are not white-listed html tags that are considered safe to render. This is a security measure.

Comment: <mark> is supported in [my Markdown-HTML](https://github.com/bjb568/Markdown-HTML), but beyond that, I don't think it's useful to have a bunch of colors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Imagine the abuse.

Done imagining?

What stops people from just using alternate colours per letter, or word? How annoying would that be?

The **bold** and *italics* support is there because these are things that can be used to empahsise specific details without being too annoying, or abuse-attracting.

What can you do with colour that you can't do (that you need to do) with **bold** or *italics*?

Comment: +1, but nidz more whitespace after "Imagine the abuse". And then, don't forget: "have you searched for dupes?" ;)

Comment: I know there are, but just lazy to perform a research :D

Comment: Oh, you should see some of the [comments on sites where Mathjax is enabled](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question/#comment3104_438)... the pain, the angry fruit salad, the agony.

Comment: @Michael !!!WANT MATHJAX NOW EVERYWHERE!!!

Comment: @nicael if you dig around on Math.SE, you can find a person who has every comment multi-colored complete with mathjax smiley faces and hearts.

Answer (score 10):

Accessibility and site design.

Not all sites use the same color scheme.  But the web doesn't speak "foreground color #1", "foreground color #2", "contrasting background color", etc; it speaks RGB.  So your hard-coded black or blue or gray will look fine on *some* sites and terrible on others -- and remember that questions can be migrated, so where you wrote it isn't necessarily where it will remain.  Plus, that color that looks fine to *you* might not provide enough contrast for someone with lesser vision, which is part of why we have userscripts running around to do things like cancel the graying-out of downvoted answers and improve the contrast on beta meta sites after the latest design adjustment.  And then there's the whole problem space of color-blindness, where what looks different to you looks the same to them.

Most people are not going to think about these issues when choosing colors.  Heck, there are tons of professionally-developed web sites out there that get this stuff wrong.  It's unreasonable to expect every one of our users to use this capability in a way that doesn't break for some people.

Besides, what's the use case?

Answer (score 4):

```python
'Because' This is 'looking fab' and if 'I wanted' to 'why not' print 'everything
like' This as 'it looks amazing?
How could you' not 'be' for This in 'every post?' #I-am-all-for-it
This class 'of post would be unbeatable' - 'that's 100% True, 'right'?
```